# Java RMI hierarchical interfaces

Tags: java, server, rmi

i'm trying to write a rmi application.

I have the following structure:
[image: class structure]

Every method in RemoteLobby throws a RemoteException. Methods in ILobby don't.

I get the following error when compiling:

> java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface; nested exception is:

Is it possible to have a interface between the class and the remote interface?

- Ahsous

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a interface between the class and the remote interface?

Yes, of course, but that means that it extends `Remote`, which implies that it is `Remote` itself, which means that it must obey the semantics required of `Remote` interfaces.

> Every method in `RemoteLobby` throws a `RemoteException.` Methods in `ILobby` don't.

And the semantics of remote interfaces are that all methods must be declared to throw `RemoteException` or one of its superclasses. So you have to adjust the methods in `ILobby.` In a case like this I would also make `ILobby` extend `Remote` directly, as well as by inheritance, to make this clear.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by removing the dependencies from the interfaces and just implement both in my class.

Comment: I don't find this at all clear. Either you should clarify this answer or delete the question.